# socket io disable the browser iteraction

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am new to websocket.I want to make the socket server only to Native Android and IOS clients.

I found socket.io library. But it works on HTTP.

Can I do ws: endpoint with socket.io ? I couldn't find anything related to ws.

because I am familiar with Java Websocket client that accepts only ws endpoint.

Is there any good scalable websocket server lib in nodejs to try out ?

Thanks.

Comment: socket.io uses a webSocket connection, but requires socket.io client and server at both ends.  All webSocket connections are initiated with an HTTP connection that is then converted to the webSocket protocol after successful connection initiation on HTTP.  A webSocket client cannot talk to a socket.io server or vice versa.  There are plain webSocket servers or socket.io servers for node.js.  Pick the one that will match the client you want to use.

Comment: Thanks. I found socket.io has good documentation and scalable options with redis and mobile clients. But for the Websocket ws client, I guess I need to find the ways to do horizontal sclabale or by myself.

Comment: Asking us here for a specific library recommendation is "off-topic" per the stack overflow rules.

Comment: [Horizontally scaling webSockets with Redis](https://goldfirestudios.com/blog/136/Horizontally-Scaling-Node.js-and-WebSockets-with-Redis).  I just found this with a simple Google search.  There's plenty out there for you to read about this issue.